# Binding two colour on a wpf template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding, colors

I created a Template in order to set a Theme for my Application.
In this Template, i created a Gradient style (composed of two colors) :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DegradeCouleurTheme" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
       <!--<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#00b6e7"/>
       <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#0086d6"/>-->
       <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{Binding Path=(m_ThemeColorGradientBegin)}"/>
       <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding Path=(m_ThemeColorGradientEnd)}"/>
   </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I would like to be able to change the two colors, so i have created a Window in order to set the colors. These colors are stored in a class "CParametres.cs" .The two colors are nextly stored in the DataBase.

**Here is my CParameters Class :** (I cleaned the class for a better view )

```
namespace Phoenix_CRM
{
    public class CParametres : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Color m_ThemeColorGradientBegin;
        public Color ThemeColorGradientBegin
        {
            get { return m_ThemeColorGradientBegin; }
            set
            {
                m_ThemeColorGradientBegin = value;
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("ThemeColorGradientBegin");
            }
        }

        private Color m_ThemeColorGradientEnd;
        public Color ThemeColorGradientEnd
        {
            get { return m_ThemeColorGradientEnd; }
            set
            {
                m_ThemeColorGradientEnd = value;
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("ThemeColorGradientEnd");
            }
        }


        public CParametres(r)
        {
           ......
        }

        public void LoadParams()
        {
            if (ReadParamFromDB() == true)
            {
                setThemeGradient(m_ThemeColorGradientBegin, m_ThemeColorGradientEnd);
            }
        }    

        public void setThemeGradient(Color ColorBegin, Color ColorEnd)
        {
            ThemeColorGradientBegin = ColorBegin;
            ThemeColorGradientEnd = ColorEnd;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void FirePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my App.xaml.cs, i created a object "CParametres" and i load the colors from the database in this object :

**In my App.xamls.cs**

```
obj_Parametres = new CParametres()
obj_Parametres .LoadParams()
```

**After this LoadParams(), the two colors are stored in the :**

m_ThemeColorGradientBegin and m_ThemeColorGradientEnd objects.

I'm trying to do the binding for this two colors to my Template, and, when i run my application, i don't have any crash, but the colors aren't apply.

I debug my application, and the LoadParams function is OK, my m_ThemeColorGradientBegin and m_ThemeColorGradientEnd objects contains colors.

Anyone could explain my why my binding is not ok ?

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards,

Nixeus

**--EDIT-- After MoHaKa tips :**

**Template :**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Phoenix_CRM">


  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DegradeCouleurTheme" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
      <!--<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#00b6e7"/>
      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#0086d6"/>-->
      <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{x:Static ns:CParametres.ThemeColorGradientBegin}"/>
      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{x:Static ns:CParametres.ThemeColorGradientBegin}"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**My CParametres.CS :**

```
    private static Color m_ThemeColorGradientBegin;
    public static Color ThemeColorGradientBegin
    {
        get { return m_ThemeColorGradientBegin; }
        set
        {
            m_ThemeColorGradientBegin = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("ThemeColorGradientBegin");
        }
    }
```

With setting static to ThemeColorGradientBegin and m_ThemeColorGradientBegin i have a compilator error on the FirePropertyChangedEvent() : Error MC3011 : Unable to find statical member ThemeColorGradientBegin on CParametres type.

Have you an idea please ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I can explain why its not working. Your Gradient uses a Path to something that WPF doesn't know in any way. It seems you want to access two private fields in a class which you instance somewhere. How should this gradient know where this instance is? Also WPF binding NEVER works on private fields, always on public properties. Besides that, MoHaKas answer is a good solution.

Comment: you already have `properties` - why not use them, `ThemeColorGradientBegin` etc.

Comment: Hello, i tried the Mohoko tips but i have a little error , i have explain there in the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS code will help you:

define this statement in your window tag.

```
xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Phoenix_CRM"
```

now using binding get the colors:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DegradeCouleurTheme" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <!--<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#00b6e7"/>
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#0086d6"/>-->
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{x:Static ns:CParametres.ThemeColorGradientBegin}"/>
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{x:Static ns:CParametres.ThemeColorGradientEnd}"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

don't forgot to change your color properties to `static`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! So, if I undertand, i need to set the ThemeColorGradientBegin and ThemeColorGradientEnd to a public static ? If i do this, i have problem with the m_ThemeColorGradientBegin and m_ThemeColorGradientEnd. I Added a new code bloc in the first post.

Comment: Solved ! I have delete the notify event i my CParametrs class to avoid the problems with the statical properties ! Thanks a lot :)